# Symfony4 Security - Url parameter after login and redirect

Tags: symfony, redirect, authentication, symfony4

I have a little url problem when I login and is redirected to a previous page.

A _GET parameter appears with the current url and it goes like that : `/admin/series?_url=%2Fadmin%2Fseries`

The current URL (the one where the user is redirected after the automatic login) is dupplicate in a _url parameter anfd i don't really want/need that.

For Example, I'm on page `/admin/series`.
When I'm logged out I'm either redirected to `/login`, either redirected to some url to login automatically (if remember_me is active).
In both ways, When i'm redirected to previous URL, the url used internally in the `check_login` is added to the "final" url I'm redirected to.
So I'm redirected into `/admin/series?_url=%2Fadmin%2Fseries`

What I would like is NOT have this URL parameter `?_url=%2Fadmin%2Fseries` in my final url.

I use Symfony4 with security package and FosUser (I don't think it's related to FosUser though)

EDIT :

Here is my `config/packages/security.yaml`
I hvae no custom listener on the login action or something similar that could interact with the default behaviour of Security component or FosUser (I have a registration controller but there is nothing inside for now).

```
security:

  encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface:
      algorithm: argon2i
      memory_cost:          16384 # Amount in KiB. 16 MiB
      time_cost:            2 # Number of iterations
      threads:              4 # Number of parallel threads

  role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

  providers:
    fos_userbundle:
      id: fos_user.user_provider.username_email

  firewalls:
    main:
      pattern: ^/
      form_login:
        provider: fos_userbundle
        csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
        always_use_default_target_path: false
        default_target_path:            admin_profile_index
        use_referer: true
      logout:       true
      anonymous:    true
      remember_me:
        secret:   '%kernel.secret%'
        lifetime: 864000
        path:     /
        domain:   ~
```

ps : If I'm not clear enough, say me I'll try to explain it better.

Comment: Can you clarify your question some? Just show what is happening now (write out the url) and what you would like it to look like.

Comment: I changed my first post, say me if it's more clear now. Basically, I just DON'T want this `_url=%2Fadmin%2Fseries` parameter after I login and is redirected.

Comment: No good ideas, but I would check your security.yaml for any options that would create this behavior, or if you have any custom login handlers maybe you have some code in there that creates this?

Comment: I juste added my security.yaml file on first post. like said, I have no listener on login actions and I don't see anything in my config that could cause this.

Comment: Sorry, I can't reproduce. Hopefully someone else will be able to help!

Comment: Okay, thank you for trying to help me. Maybe it comes form my server config, I'm accessing it from a directory the full URL is `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/project/public/admin/series`. I don't know how it could interfer with the redirect exactly but ... I have no other idea for now.